# Parsing key-value pairs out of a TSV in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R, so I don't think as clearly in vector-space as more-experienced users do. I have a data frame that's formatted like so:

```
              metric timestamp               value           tag1     tag2   tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6 tag7 tag8 tag9 tag10
1 dummy.random.unif 1367848802  0.9936670064926147 host=localhost blah=foo   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
2 dummy.random.unif 1367848822 0.19621700048446655 host=localhost blah=bar   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
3 dummy.linear      1367848842                97.6 shmoo=whatever NA         NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
4 dummy.random.unif 1367848862  0.3171229958534241 host=localhost blah=foo   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
5 dummy.linear      1367848882                97.7 shmoo=whatever NA         NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
6 dummy.random.unif 1367848902  0.2197140008211136 host=localhost blah=foo   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

As you can see, the columns `tag1:tag10` contain key-value pairs. But not always the same keys, and not always the same number of keys. I want to convert this data frame to something more like this, which is more convenient for consumption:

```
              metric timestamp               value   tag.host tag.blah tag.shmoo 
1 dummy.random.unif 1367848802  0.9936670064926147  localhost      foo        NA
2 dummy.random.unif 1367848822 0.19621700048446655  localhost      bar        NA
3 dummy.linear      1367848842                97.6         NA       NA  whatever
4 dummy.random.unif 1367848862  0.3171229958534241  localhost      foo        NA
5 dummy.linear      1367848882                97.7         NA       NA  whatever
6 dummy.random.unif 1367848902  0.2197140008211136  localhost      foo  whatever
```

Now I know I could do this procedurally, but it would be clunky, and I've heard that the correct way to use R is to think about operations on entire vectors (rather than looping over them). I've spent a few hours trying to figure out the right permutation of `do.call`, `daply`, `strsplit`, and so on, but I'm not getting anywhere.

What is a clean, R-ish way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read this on how to make a good reproducible example and update your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `DF` is the input data frame then convert it from wide to long form using `melt`, remove NA rows, split the tags into `tag.name` and `tag.value` and reshape it back to wide as indicated:

```
library(reshape2)
m <- na.omit(melt(DF, id = 1:3, value.name = "tag"))
m.tr <- transform(m, tag.name = sub("=.*", "", tag), 
                     tag.value = sub(".*=", "", tag))
dcast(metric + timestamp + metric + value ~ tag.name, data=m.tr, 
      value.var="tag.value")
```

Swap `metric` and `timestamp` in the last line if its desired to have the output in timestamp order. The result of the last line is:

```
             metric  timestamp     value blah      host    shmoo
1      dummy.linear 1367848842 97.600000 <NA>      <NA> whatever
2      dummy.linear 1367848882 97.700000 <NA>      <NA> whatever
3 dummy.random.unif 1367848802  0.993667  foo localhost     <NA>
4 dummy.random.unif 1367848822  0.196217  bar localhost     <NA>
5 dummy.random.unif 1367848862  0.317123  foo localhost     <NA>
6 dummy.random.unif 1367848902  0.219714  foo localhost     <NA>
```

Comment: Holy crap. I hope one day if I work hard enough I will be as good at this mode of thinking as you are. Thanks.